# Creating Internal Links in General Link Fields is Failing in Sitecore 8.2 Environments

Tags: links, field

We have a few templates in our project which use the `General Link` field type.  We're finding them unpredictable.

In our Staging environment, by clicking the `Insert Link` field to create a link to another content item the Insert Link dialog is displayed. This allows us to navigate the content tree to select the item to be linked to. However, upon selecting the desired target we don't get the Link Details display, and on clicking the Insert button to commit the selection and close the dialog, nothing happens.  In our Development (pre-Staging) environment we can't navigate the content tree at all.  But on some of our local development machines, it works fine.

The only telltale hint we've found thus far is a JavaScript error in the browser developer tools in the Staging environment indicating a function called `insertInternalLinkResult() isn't defined`.  This seems to indicate that one or more of the implementing Sitecore files may be missing or out of date, but we're unable to track it further than that.  Has anyone else had similar problems with this field type, or has other pertinent insights to this problem?

Comment: Did you upgrade Sitecore?

Comment: You'd probably be better off asking this in the [Sitecore Slack Channel](https://sitecore.chat) - this would likely need some debugging and discussion, which is not the best format for SSE

Answer (score 0):

I believe the function `insertInternalLinkResult()` is defined in

```
Sitecore/shell/client/applications/dialogs/insertlinkviatreedialog.js
```

Please can you confirm the file hasn't been removed during any upgrade process? If missing add from the vanilla install.